# retrieving data from localStorage unexpected number

Tags: javascript, local-storage

My problem is when I run this code I get an unexpected number error. This site has helped me so much but can't seem to get why this is happening.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>help</title>
<script>
    var object1 ={
    number:0,
    name:" ",
    list:[ ]}
    var storedAt = 2;
    var item="";

function doStuff() {
    object1.list.push("hello");
    object1.list.push("world");
    object1.number = 5;
    object1.name = "des"
    item = JSON.stringify(object1)
    store();
      }

       function store() { 
           localStorage.setItem("item"+storedAt,item+storedAt); for (var i=0;i<localStorage.length; i++){ var key = localStorage.key(i); if (key.substring(0,1) =="") {  var value = localStorage.getItem(key);  }}  return;}


       function getBack() {
          var di =JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("item"+storedAt))
          alert("display  = "+di.number);
            }
         </script>
         </head>
         <body>
         <input type="button"id="doStuff"value = "Do Stuff" onclick = doStuff();>
         <input type="button"id="getBack"value = "get Back" onclick = getBack();>
         </body>
         </html>
```

When I run this, the problem shows in the alert.

Comment: curious: why did you choose 'localStorage.setItem("item"+storedAt,item+storedAt)' instead of  'localStorage["item"+storedAt]=item+storedAt;'? i'm wondering why folks use the localStorage methods instead of property access.

Answer (score 1):

Change this `localStorage.setItem("item"+storedAt,item+storedAt);` into this `localStorage.setItem("item"+storedAt,item);`, so now it should make more sense.

If not, then what you are doing is altering the state of the json string with the `storedAt` value, then when you are trying to parse it JSON.parse throws the error because the json is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>help</title>
    <script>
        var object1 ={
            number:0,
            name:" ",
            list:[ ]}
            var storedAt = 2;
            var item="";

            function doStuff() {
                object1.list.push("hello");
                object1.list.push("world");
                object1.number = 5;
                object1.name = "des"
                item = JSON.stringify(object1)
                store();
            }

            function store() { 
                localStorage.setItem("item"+storedAt, item);
                for (var i=0;i<localStorage.length; i++){
                    var key = localStorage.key(i); if (key.substring(0,1) =="") {  var value = localStorage.getItem(key);  }}  return;
                }


                function getBack() {
                    var di =JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("item"+storedAt))
                    alert("display  = "+di.number);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button"id="doStuff"value = "Do Stuff" onclick = doStuff();>
        <input type="button"id="getBack"value = "get Back" onclick = getBack();>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you setItem, you append storedAt to the Object, and JSON.parse fails because isn´t valid object.

Comment: thank you very much Ruben much help I was so close it was driving me mad.